# Cheroke URL rewrite rule

Tags: rewrite, cherokee

I'm looking to create a URL rewrite rule for Cherokee 1.2.2 web server where the URL is:

```
http://example.com/pricing?remove=358&referer=cHJpY2luZw==
```

and I would like:

```
http://example.com/pricing
```

I also have a rule setup to remove index.php from the the URLs. That rule being:

```
internal | ^/(.*)$ | /index.php?q=$
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this regex, substituted to `pricing`, should work:

```
^/pricing\?
```

Are you sure you want to lose the GET parameters like that?